# Electronically Signing a Document Already Signed by Client

Tags: docusignapi

We recently integrated Docusign to our CRM. What this did was allowed us to auto send our contract to clients when they filled out a form. This worked out great, however, the template we initially used did not have our CEO's signature already signed to it, so we have ~100 contracts in Docusign which are signed by the client but not by our CEO.

In docusign, is there a way for us to electronically sign a document already signed by the client?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

- Create a new document using the completed PDF
- Clone the original document and start over

Documentation [here](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-add-signatures-to-a-completed-document)